# Kustomize delete fields during patch

Tags: kubernetes, patch, kustomize

i'm trying to path deployment by using kustomize
i need to change only env in the spec.template.spec.containers.
but during kustomisation other fields are deleting too

tree:

```
k8s
|_base
  |_ deployment.yaml
  |_ kustomisation.yaml
  |_ svc.yaml
|_overlays
  |prod
    |_ kustomisation.yaml
    |_ patches.yaml
  |_stage
  |_dev
```

base.deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
  name: __NAME__
  namespace: __NAME__
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: __NAME__
        app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: __NAME__
        image: __IMAGE__ 
        env:
          - name: name_
            value: value_
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1500m
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext:
          runAsGroup: 1001
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

overlays.prod.kustomization.yaml

```
resources:
- ../../base/
patches:
- target:
    kind: Deployment
    name: __NAME__
  path: patches.yaml
```

overlays.prod.patches.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: __NAME__
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  __NAME__
        env:
        - name: ENV_VAR_NAME_1
          value: new_value_1
        - name: ENV_VAR_NAME_2
          value: new_value_2
```

after the command  `kubectl kustomize overlays/prod/ -o stage_test.yaml`
output is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
  name: __NAME__
  namespace: __NAME__
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: __NAME__
        app.kubernetes.io/name: __NAME__
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ENV_VAR_NAME_1
          value: new_value_1
        - name: ENV_VAR_NAME_2
          value: new_value_2
        name: __NAME__
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

as you can see kustomise - deleting probes, ports and othes stuff

How to avoid deleting? i need only to change envs.
ofc if i put all other stuff into patches.yaml kustomize will add it into output

tried to set annotation
annotations:
kustomize.kubernetes.io/ignore-patches: "true"
and run kustomize with it (not worked - same output)

pathes to patchesStrategicMerge (worked identically)

versions if it's matter:

- Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
- Client Version: 1.26
- Platform: darwin/arm64

Comment: There are some indentation problems in `patches.yaml` and `overlays/prod/kustomization.yaml` that render them invalid; you should fix those in your question.

Comment: @larsks fixed here, in the code i've got normal indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause here is that you've defined your Deployment as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
```

But that's not the correct `apiVersion` for a Deployment; it should be:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
```

Support for the `extensions/v1beta1` API was [removed in Kubernetes 1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).

Kustomize "knows" about a regular Kubernetes Deployment and will properly merge your configuration; with that single change (and using Kustomize v5.0.1), your patch works correctly.

Compare before the change:

```
$ kustomize build overlays/prod | yq .spec.template.spec.containers
[
  {
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "ENV_VAR_NAME_1",
        "value": "new_value_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "ENV_VAR_NAME_2",
        "value": "new_value_2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "__NAME__"
  }
]
```

To:

```
$ sed -i '/^apiVersion:/ s|apiVersion:.*|apiVersion: apps/v1|' base/deployment.yaml
$ kustomize build overlays/prod | yq .spec.template.spec.containers
[
  {
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "ENV_VAR_NAME_1",
        "value": "new_value_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "ENV_VAR_NAME_2",
        "value": "new_value_2"
      },
      {
        "name": "name_",
        "value": "value_"
      }
    ],
    "image": "__IMAGE__",
    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
    "livenessProbe": {
      "failureThreshold": 3,
      "httpGet": {
        "path": "/healthz",
        "port": 8081,
        "scheme": "HTTP"
      },
      "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
      "periodSeconds": 20,
      "successThreshold": 1,
      "timeoutSeconds": 1
    },
    "name": "__NAME__",
    "ports": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8081,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "readinessProbe": {
      "failureThreshold": 3,
      "httpGet": {
        "path": "/healthz",
        "port": 8081,
        "scheme": "HTTP"
      },
      "initialDelaySeconds": 5,
      "periodSeconds": 10,
      "successThreshold": 1,
      "timeoutSeconds": 1
    },
    "resources": {
      "limits": {
        "cpu": "1500m",
        "memory": "1Gi"
      },
      "requests": {
        "cpu": "250m",
        "memory": "128Mi"
      }
    },
    "securityContext": {
      "runAsGroup": 1001,
      "runAsUser": 1001
    },
    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
    "terminationMessagePolicy": "File"
  }
]
```

---

If you are forced to use the `extensions/v1beta1` API, you may want to look at [this document](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/customOpenAPIschema.md) for instructions on how to provide Kustomize with information about how to handle merges for custom resource types.

[This article](https://tech.aabouzaid.com/2022/11/set-openapi-patch-strategy-for-kubernetes-custom-resources-kustomize.html) explores the process in more detail.